# One finger zoom + rotate in Android

Tags: android, zooming, rotation

I was developing a zoom control in android based on the tutorial: [Android one finger zoom tutorial](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/developerworld/2010/07/07/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-4/)

```
public abstract class Dynamics {
/**
 * The maximum delta time, in milliseconds, between two updates
 */
private static final int MAX_TIMESTEP = 50;

/** The current position */
protected float mPosition;

/** The current velocity */
protected float mVelocity;

/** The current maximum position */
protected float mMaxPosition = Float.MAX_VALUE;

/** The current minimum position */
protected float mMinPosition = -Float.MAX_VALUE;

/** The time of the last update */
protected long mLastTime = 0;

/**
 * Sets the state of the dynamics object. Should be called before starting
 * to call update.
 * 
 * @param position The current position.
 * @param velocity The current velocity in pixels per second.
 * @param now The current time
 */
public void setState(final float position, final float velocity, final long now) {
    mVelocity = velocity;
    mPosition = position;
    mLastTime = now;
}

/**
 * Returns the current position. Normally used after a call to update() in
 * order to get the updated position.
 * 
 * @return The current position
 */
public float getPosition() {
    return mPosition;
}

/**
 * Gets the velocity. Unit is in pixels per second.
 * 
 * @return The velocity in pixels per second
 */
public float getVelocity() {
    return mVelocity;
}

/**
 * Used to find out if the list is at rest, that is, has no velocity and is
 * inside the the limits. Normally used to know if more calls to update are
 * needed.
 * 
 * @param velocityTolerance Velocity is regarded as 0 if less than
 *            velocityTolerance
 * @param positionTolerance Position is regarded as inside the limits even
 *            if positionTolerance above or below
 * 
 * @return true if list is at rest, false otherwise
 */
public boolean isAtRest(final float velocityTolerance, final float positionTolerance) {
    final boolean standingStill = Math.abs(mVelocity) < velocityTolerance;
    final boolean withinLimits = mPosition - positionTolerance < mMaxPosition
            && mPosition + positionTolerance > mMinPosition;
    return standingStill && withinLimits;
}

/**
 * Sets the maximum position.
 * 
 * @param maxPosition The maximum value of the position
 */
public void setMaxPosition(final float maxPosition) {
    mMaxPosition = maxPosition;
}

/**
 * Sets the minimum position.
 * 
 * @param minPosition The minimum value of the position
 */
public void setMinPosition(final float minPosition) {
    mMinPosition = minPosition;
}

/**
 * Updates the position and velocity.
 * 
 * @param now The current time
 */
public void update(final long now) {
    int dt = (int)(now - mLastTime);
    if (dt > MAX_TIMESTEP) {
        dt = MAX_TIMESTEP;
    }

    onUpdate(dt);

    mLastTime = now;
}

/**
 * Gets the distance to the closest limit (max and min position).
 * 
 * @return If position is more than max position: distance to max position. If
 *         position is less than min position: distance to min position. If
 *         within limits: 0
 */
protected float getDistanceToLimit() {
    float distanceToLimit = 0;

    if (mPosition > mMaxPosition) {
        distanceToLimit = mMaxPosition - mPosition;
    } else if (mPosition < mMinPosition) {
        distanceToLimit = mMinPosition - mPosition;
    }

    return distanceToLimit;
}

/**
 * Updates the position and velocity.
 * 
 * @param dt The delta time since last time
 */
abstract protected void onUpdate(int dt);
}
```

---

```
public class SpringDynamics extends Dynamics {

/** Friction factor */
private float mFriction;

/** Spring stiffness factor */
private float mStiffness;

/** Spring damping */
private float mDamping;

/**
 * Set friction parameter, friction physics are applied when inside of snap
 * bounds.
 * 
 * @param friction Friction factor
 */
public void setFriction(float friction) {
    mFriction = friction;
}

/**
 * Set spring parameters, spring physics are applied when outside of snap
 * bounds.
 * 
 * @param stiffness Spring stiffness
 * @param dampingRatio Damping ratio, < 1 underdamped, > 1 overdamped
 */
public void setSpring(float stiffness, float dampingRatio) {
    mStiffness = stiffness;
    mDamping = dampingRatio * 2 * (float)Math.sqrt(stiffness);
}

/**
 * Calculate acceleration at the current state
 * 
 * @return Current acceleration
 */
private float calculateAcceleration() {
    float acceleration;

    final float distanceFromLimit = getDistanceToLimit();
    if (distanceFromLimit != 0) {
        acceleration = distanceFromLimit * mStiffness - mDamping * mVelocity;
    } else {
        acceleration = -mFriction * mVelocity;
    }

    return acceleration;
}

@Override
protected void onUpdate(int dt) {
    // Calculate dt in seconds as float
    final float fdt = dt / 1000f;

    // Calculate current acceleration
    final float a = calculateAcceleration();

    // Calculate next position based on current velocity and acceleration
    mPosition += mVelocity * fdt + .5f * a * fdt * fdt;

    // Update velocity
    mVelocity += a * fdt;
}

}
```

Can someone give me some idea as to how to incorporate rotation of image into this as well (similar to the iphone pinch)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To rotate image, see [ImageView#setImageMatrix()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageMatrix%28android.graphics.Matrix%29) and the [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) class.  Using `Matrix`, you can perform several types of transformations against the image, including rotation.